# Occasional IE SCRIPT1014 error

Tags: javascript, iis, internet-explorer-9, iis-7.5

I'm not expecting an answer, just thought I'd throw this out there...

I have an ASP.NET site running on IIS 7.5. Relatively often, maybe 10% of requests, one or two users receive errors while loading javascript resources.

One of the users (IE9) recorded the errors in the F12 tools. There are a couple dozen javascript files on our page, and most of them errored out with the following:

```
SCRIPT1014: Invalid character
xxxxx.js, line 1 character 11
```

All of the ones that errored give exactly `line 1 character 11`. Drilling down into the script files in IE through this error message, everything looked fine - the content that IE showed for these files was exactly what it should be.

But these script files, including jQuery, some third party plugins, and some internal scripts, apparently blew up completely when loading. All of our js files are hosted on our servers - no CDNs.

However, a few of the javascript files apparently were more successful, just erroring out with `'jQuery' is undefined` or similar, telling me those must have at least started to execute properly.

Compression is enabled and working properly. I considered the possibility that maybe compression was to blame, and IE was attempting to execute gzip-compressed script without first decompressing it. However, when I force gzip bytes down a response, IE errors with `line 1 character 1`, and these are consistently `character 11`.

IE9 in "InPrivate" mode works fine - not a single error.

Something that may be related - the browser isn't properly using cached content. When loading the page from my machine (also IE9), the `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match` request headers are sent every time on a refresh, which means the response comes back as a 304 every time, and regular navigation always simply uses cache with no requests. On the problem machine, about 1/3 of the time, the browser requests these files again, with no headers, which means they come back with 200's.

I watched Fiddler, and even with that weirdness, all requests and responses are properly formatted and contain good content, so while the caching thing is weird and possibly related, it does not appear to be the direct cause.

Of course I tried to reproduce a couple thousand times on my machine, manually and through Fiddler, and everything was always perfect. And the user can't reproduce on demand. So I can't even confirm whether it's a server or browser issue, or if it's unique to IE or IE9.

Any thoughts on what could cause this specific scenario? The `line 1 character 11` thing is what leads me to believe there's some kind of pattern here.

Comment: I bet the server returns invalid content during an ajax request. When things seems inconsistent, data is often to blame.

Comment: @plalx Thanks, I thought about AJAX, but this happens just when loading the static javascript files in the first place - the errors occur before any AJAX calls could fire (the `jQuery is undefined` error happens because jQuery never got loaded in the first place, and all of our AJAX calls are through jQuery - so no AJAX is even attempted).